# Benefit of Universal Variable formulation for elliptical only cases

Tags: orbit, kepler-telescope

I have been reading, and understand that for robust systems dealing with all types of orbits in a two body system universal variables approach has been favored. My question is, if I am strictly dealing with circular and elliptical orbits only, is there any benefit to the [universal variable approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_variable_formulation) over traditional Kepler using Newton iterations to solve for anomalies?

Comment: These may be helpful: [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236012521_Lambert_Universal_Variable_Algorithm), [2](http://web.mit.edu/wisdom/www/wisdom-hernandez.pdf), [3](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1965AJ.....70..309H). For the last one click "print this article" to view the PDF.